# Symfony2 Doctrine, generate:entities

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I learn Symfony2 and i have a problem with database. I use this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/doctrine.html
I have Product.php class, but when i try execute this command:
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Product
i get error:
"Class "AppBundle\Entity\Product" is not a valid entity or mapped super class."

This is my Product.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Marcin
 * Date: 20.12.2015
 * Time: 23:33
*/

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="product")
*/

class Product
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
 */
protected $price;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $description;
}
```

Other people have the same error, but they don't have "@ORM\Entity" in their code. I have, but problem still existing. 
I have no idea what's going on...

**Update:**

This is fragment of config.yml:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     localhost
    port:     3306
    dbname:   db_name
    user:     db_user
    password: db_password
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #     path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
```

**Updated2:**

I changed config.yml:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    # naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    # auto_mapping: true
    entity_managers:
      default:
        mappings:
          AppBundle: ~
```

And when i use: 
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
I get: 
"You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors."

Comment: Try to define your entity using symfony shorthand, like this `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Product`

Comment: Can you copy and paste the Doctrine block in your config.yml? I'd guess it's something to do with annotations or mapping, as you PHP entity looks correct.

Comment: @AJCerqueti I've edited my post.

Comment: @Robin71 I don't think you need all of that. [example](http://pastebin.com/jqEPQ50s)

Comment: @AJCerqueti When i used code from expample and executed "php app/console doctrine:mapping:info" I got: "You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.". Generating setters and getters still doesn't work.

Comment: @Robin71 do you have a Github you can add me to, and I'll have a look? Will then update this with an answer!

Comment: @AJCerqueti I don't use Github or something similar  :/

Comment: @AJCerqueti I've reinstalled my application and everything is working. I have no idea what was wrong.